# HIVE select where date between, but its a string YYYYMMDD, not numeric date format?

Tags: sql, date, hive

so I'm trying to learn how to deal with this.

the key partition column is "date" as a string (YYYYMMDD).

so its a character string, not a numeric date format.

I'm having trouble understanding how I can WHERE filter off this by normal date ranges like

where date > CURRENT_DATE -30

or

WHERE date BETWEEN '20210512' AND '20210517'

How does this work? Should the date column be converted first?

This is SQL in a HIVE database.

Comment: tag the database you are using

Comment: You have to cast the "date" field to a date type. As you did not tell which database you are using, I cannot help you with the right function to use as it can be different for every sql db.

Comment: Sorry. This is SQL in a HIVE database.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to convert the comparison date to a string.  Many databases support `to_char()`:

```
where date > to_char(current_date - 30, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Those that do not would have some other function to convert the date to a string.

Note that this formulation allows the use of indexes and table partitions to optimize the query.

Comment: How would I do this for a 'between' search? like to search a specific date range?

Comment: @surfer349 . . . Your `between` version should work fine.

Comment: i've tried that but get no returns.

the only thing that I can get to work is this format.

where date > '20210610'

Comment: @surfer349 . . . Maybe you have no values in that time period.